# Azure.Storage.Files.Shares wont install on .Net MAUI using .Net 7

Tags: .net, maui, azure-file-share

When trying to install Azure.Storage.Files.Shares on a empty .NET MAUI app (created directly from the VS 2022 17.4.4 wizard) I get a series off incompatibilities. If have tried a simple Console app and the problem is the same.

- Restoring packages for C:\Users\brend\source\repos\MauiApp7\MauiApp7\MauiApp7.csproj...
- NU1202: Package Azure.Storage.Files.Shares 12.12.1 is not compatible with net7.0-android33.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0). Package Azure.Storage.Files.Shares 12.12.1 does not support any target frameworks.
- NU1202: Package Azure.Storage.Common 12.13.0 is not compatible with net7.0-android33.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0). Package Azure.Storage.Common 12.13.0 does not support any target frameworks.
- NU1202: Package System.Text.Json 4.7.2 is not compatible with net7.0-android33.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0). Package System.Text.Json 4.7.2 does not support any target frameworks.
- NU

Any ideas what I am missing?

I expected the Nuget package to install, just like the demos in the Microsoft examples

Comment: Instead of `net7.0-android33`, the MAUI project should probably only target `net7.0-android`. Try changing that in the .csproj file of your MAUI app.

Comment: Can you tell us which microsoft examples are you trying? or have you tried restarting or cleaning the project?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the package `Azure.Storage.Files.Shares` is available for MAUI.

You can check the dependencies section of the nuget package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Files.Shares/#dependencies-body-tab). The only target it supports is `.NETStandard 2.0`

```
[.NETStandard 2.0]
Azure.Storage.Common (>= 12.13.0)
System.Text.Json (>= 4.7.2)
```

Compare it with, for example the package which supports MAUI like [ZXing library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Maui/0.3.0-preview.1) which has the required target `.net7.0-android33.0`

```
[net7.0-android33.0]
Xamarin.AndroidX.Camera.Camera2 (>= 1.1.0)
Xamarin.AndroidX.Camera.Lifecycle (>= 1.1.0)
Xamarin.AndroidX.Camera.View (>= 1.1.0)
ZXing.Net (>= 0.16.8)
```

## Edit

As @ewerspej pointed out, the library indeed has `net7.0-android` target if we look in framwework section on nuget package site.
I tested out by creating new MAUI project with `net7.0-android` as target framework and also by changing to specific `net7.0-android33.0` as well in `.csproj` file, I was able to install the package correctly in both the cases!

Comment: .NET 7.0 is listed under Frameworks. Generally .NET Standard 2.0 is supported by .NET 7.0.  I think the problem is the specific target, instead of `net7.0-android33`, the MAUI project should only target `net7.0-android`.

Answer (score 0):

I did discover that the Nuget cache must have been corrupted in some way. I did try to clear the cache using the tools in VS 2022, however an error occurred. After reinstalling Visual Studio I was able to use the Azure.Storage.Files.Shares  package.

As pointed out in one of replies net7.0-android and net7.0-android33.0 had something to do with the problem, but I was not able to isolate it.